# Creating a running variance column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to create a column in a MySQL table that calculates the running variance (or standard deviation, whichever would be easiest) of the last five values of another column. I am currently ordering the data using three variables: ID, date, and a counter (the counter ascends from 1 for each ID-date pairing). So each time a new ID-date combination begins, I'd like this new variance column to reset as well. Here is a little sample of what I'm going for:

```
+----+--------+---------+-------+--------------------------+
| ID |  date  | counter | value |        var(value)        |
+----+--------+---------+-------+--------------------------+
| 11 | 1/1/13 |       1 | 2.1   | var(2.1)                 |
| 11 | 1/1/13 |       2 | 2.4   | var(2.1,2.4)             |
| 11 | 1/1/13 |       3 | 2.3   | var(2.1,2.4,2.3)         |
| 11 | 1/1/13 |       4 | 2.5   | var(2.1,2.4,2.3,2.5)     |
| 11 | 1/1/13 |       5 | 2.3   | var(2.1,2.4,2.3,2.5,2.3) |
| 11 | 1/1/13 |       6 | 2.5   | var(2.4,2.3,2.5,2.3,2.5) |
| 11 | 1/3/13 |       1 | 5.4   | var(5.4)                 |
| 11 | 1/3/13 |       2 | 4.3   | var(5.4,4.3)             |
| 11 | 1/3/13 |       3 | 3.4   | var(5.4,4.3,3.4)         |
| 11 | 1/3/13 |       4 | 2.1   | var(5.4,4.3,3.4,2.1)     |
+----+--------+---------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Does anyone know how this can be done in MySQL? I haven't found a solution to anything question similar to this one out there.

Thanks so much!

Comment: It can be done, but it's a bit of work. Let us see some effort from you first - show an attempt. This is not a coding service.

Comment: or maybe we just give you the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can *group* a self-join using a suitable aggregation function, such as [`VARIANCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_variance):

```
SELECT   a.*, VARIANCE(b.value)
FROM     my_table a
    JOIN my_table b ON b.ID       = a.ID
                   AND b.date     = a.date
                   AND b.counter <= a.counter
GROUP BY a.ID, a.date, a.counter, a.value
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1579/1/0).

Comment: +1 nice. haven't come across this agg function before

Answer (score 0):

The variance is the average of the sum of the squares of the differences between each value and the average.  So, you can do this, with a lot of joins and arithmetic.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when t1.date is null then 0
             when t2.date is null
             then (pow(t.value - (t.value + t1.value) / 2, 2) +
                  pow(t1.value - (t.value + t1.value) / 2, 2))/2
             when t3.date is null
             then (pow(t.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value) / 3, 2) +
                   pow(t1.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value) / 3, 2) + 
                   pow(t2.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value) / 3, 2)
                  ) / 3
             when t4.date is null
             then (pow(t.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value) / 4, 2) +
                   pow(t1.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value) / 4, 2) + 
                   pow(t2.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value) / 4, 2) +
                   pow(t3.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value) / 4, 2)
                  ) / 4
             else (pow(t.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value + t4.value) / 5, 2) +
                   pow(t1.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value + t4.value) / 5, 2) + 
                   pow(t2.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value + t4.value) / 5, 2) +
                   pow(t3.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value + t4.value) / 5, 2) +
                   pow(t4.value - (t.value + t1.value + t2.value + t3.value + t4.value) / 5, 2)
                  ) / 5
        end) as var
from t left outer join
     t t1
     on t.date = t1.date and t.counter = t1.counter + 1 left outer join
     t t2
     on t.date = t2.date and t.counter = t2.counter + 2 left outer join
     t t3
     on t.date = t3.date and t.counter = t3.counter + 3 left outer join
     t t4
     on t.date = t4.date and t.counter = t4.counter + 4;
```

Comment: Wow.  Really?  Have I missed something?  :/